# jQuery-UI Position not work when the scrollbar

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

There are two things:

- Or be a jerk
- Or I found a bug

I have a webpage with an iframe.

I want to place an icon in the lower left of the iframe. So I thought I could do this with jquery-ui position.

here is my attempt does not work:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"
        "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
    <title>test positionLogo</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8/themes/redmond/jquery-ui.css"
          type="text/css" media="screen"/>
    <style type="text/css">
        div.positionLogo {
            width: 64px;
            height: 64px;
            position: absolute;
            display: block;
            text-align: center;
            background: #FFFFFF url(http://qooxdoo.org/_media/stackoverflow.png) no-repeat center;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>

<h2>Header</h2>

<iframe id="idIframe" name="idIframe" scrolling="no" height="1600px" width="100%" src="http://www.google.it"
        frameborder="0"></iframe>

<div class="positionLogo"></div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $(".positionLogo").position({
            of:$("#idIframe"),
            my:"left bottom",
            at:"left bottom"
        });
    });
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

the nice thing is that if you **change** the **height** of the **iframe** option
`height="1600px"` to `height="300px"`

The widget works correctly! :S

How is it possible?
Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you need is to use collision option of position widget (set it to none). Default value is flip which tries to automatically adjust position for you (to visible part of a page)

http://jqueryui.com/demos/position/#option-collision

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        $(".positionLogo").position({
            of:$("#idIframe"),
            my:"left bottom",
            at:"left bottom",
            collision: 'none'
        });
    });
```